# Upgraded to Firebase and having many issues now restarting app

Tags: android, firebase, android-anr-dialog, firebase-crash-reporting

I've recently upgraded to firebase from gcm. Which forced me to upgrade my build tools ect. The app uses Play Services to check subscription status, and other wise the it's a basic Push To Talk application.  Everything was running fine on GCM with build tools 22.*.*. I've implemented firebase just fine and it works properly. The problem I'm having is no matter which three of my activities I launch now or from where (widget, notification, icon) results in an ANR. Mind you the first time I launch the activities they run as expected. Any activity launched the second time gives the ANR. What is going on here?

log errors

```
06-11 02:45:49.913 32009-32009/com.cb3g.channel19 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
06-11 02:45:59.883 32009-32030/com.cb3g.channel19 E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cb3g.channel19-3/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cb3g.channel19-3/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
06-11 02:45:59.883 32009-32030/com.cb3g.channel19 W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.cb3g.channel19 rsrc of package com.google.android.gms
06-11 02:49:36.923 32009-32009/com.cb3g.channel19 W/AudioManager: setStreamMute is deprecated. adjustStreamVolume should be used instead.
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {

        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cb3g.channel19"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 278
        versionName "2.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cb3g.channel19">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/smallicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:theme="@style/mytheme"
        android:value="AIzaSyadfadfaLJKLKJkldfk">

        <activity
            android:name=".main_activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateAlwaysHidden"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".settings_activity"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/pmstyle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".login_activity"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/mytheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="247483647">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".radio_service"
            android:exported="false"/>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".channel19">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/channel19_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What would cause the ANR upon returning to the Activity?

UPDATE: without the Firebase compile app runs correctly. Ive added the firebase crash compile to attempt to get a Firebase log of the situation to no avail here are the dependencies.

```
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.2'
```

Comment: Check logcat or aldo integrate firebase crash reporting to see exact reason for ANR in firebase console

Comment: Sure enough. I remove the firebased import and the Firebase Recieiving service and the problem is removed. Hopefully somebody has been through this before and can help me out here.

Comment: I don't see any any reference to an ANR in the logs you posted.  The one log line that looks like an error is actually ignorable.  Could you find and post the more relevant lines of the ANR that's causing the program to stop?